# transaction.addToBackStack(null) doesn't make sense

Tags: android-fragments

transaction.addToBackStack(null) doesn't make sense?

my program is set to press the button and add the fragment,before:
[image]
after pressed:
[image]

my code is:

```
  anotherFragment anotherFragment = new anotherFragment();
  android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.right_container,anotherFragment);
  transaction.addToBackStack(null);
  transaction.commit();
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the Genymotion's bug

serveral minutes later,I restart it in genymotion emulator. It works!